# Netty: TCP Client Server File transfer: Exception TooLongFrameException:

Tags: tcp, netty, file-transfer

I am new to netty and I am trying to design a solution as below for transfer of file from Server to Client over TCP:

```
1. Zero copy based file transfer in case of non-ssl based transfer (Using default region of the file)
2. ChunkedFile transfer in case of SSL based transfer.
```

The Client - Server file transfer works in this way:

```
1. The client sends the location of the file to be transfered
2. Based on the location (sent by the client) the server transfers the file to the client
```

The file content could be anything (String /image /pdf etc) and any size.

Now, I get this **TooLongFrameException:**  at the Server side, though the server is just decoding the path received from the client, for running the code mentioned below (Server/Client).

```
io.netty.handler.codec.TooLongFrameException: Adjusted frame length exceeds 65536: 215542494061 - discarded
    at io.netty.handler.codec.LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.fail(LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.java:522)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.failIfNecessary(LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.java:500)
```

Now, **My question is:**

1. Am I wrong with the order of **Encoders and Decoders** and its configuration? If so, what is the correct way to configure it to receive a file from the server?
2. I went through few related StackOverflow posts [SO Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43592095/lengthfieldbasedframedecoder-not-parsing-correctly-when-buffer-size-is-less-than?rq=1),[SO Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489490/correct-usage-of-netty-lengthfieldprepender-and-lengthfieldbasedframedecoder?rq=1) , [SO Q3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24979610/netty-defaultchannelpipeline-exceptioncaught), [SO Q4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27357672/sending-file-from-server-to-client-by-using-netty-io). I got to know about the LengthFieldBasedDecoder, but I didn't get to know how to configure its corresponding LengthFieldPrepender at the Server (Encoding side). Is it even required at all?

Please point me into the right direction.

FileClient:

```
public final class FileClient {

    static final boolean SSL = System.getProperty("ssl") != null;
    static final int PORT = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("port", SSL ? "8992" : "8023"));
    static final String HOST = System.getProperty("host", "127.0.0.1");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Configure SSL.
        final SslContext sslCtx;
        if (SSL) {
            SelfSignedCertificate ssc = new SelfSignedCertificate();
            sslCtx = SslContextBuilder.forServer(ssc.certificate(), ssc.privateKey()).build();
        } else {
            sslCtx = null;
        }

        // Configure the client
        EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();

        try {

            Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
            b.group(group)
            .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
            .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
            .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                @Override
                public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                    ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
                    if (sslCtx != null) {
                        pipeline.addLast(sslCtx.newHandler(ch.alloc(), HOST, PORT));
                    }
                    pipeline.addLast("frameDecoder", new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(64*1024, 0, 8));
                    pipeline.addLast("frameEncoder", new LengthFieldPrepender(4));
                    pipeline.addLast(new ObjectDecoder(ClassResolvers.cacheDisabled(null)));
                    pipeline.addLast(new ObjectEncoder());
                    pipeline.addLast( new FileClientHandler());                }
             });


            // Start the server.
            ChannelFuture f = b.connect(HOST,PORT).sync();

            // Wait until the server socket is closed.
            f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            // Shut down all event loops to terminate all threads.
            group.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}
```

FileClientHandler:

```
public class FileClientHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        String filePath = "/Users/Home/Documents/Data.pdf";
        ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(filePath.getBytes()));
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("File Client Handler Read method...");
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        cause.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

FileServer:

```
/**
 * Server that accept the path of a file and echo back its content.
 */
public final class FileServer {

    static final boolean SSL = System.getProperty("ssl") != null;
    static final int PORT = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("port", SSL ? "8992" : "8023"));

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Configure SSL.
        final SslContext sslCtx;
        if (SSL) {
            SelfSignedCertificate ssc = new SelfSignedCertificate();
            sslCtx = SslContextBuilder.forServer(ssc.certificate(), ssc.privateKey()).build();
        } else {
            sslCtx = null;
        }

        // Configure the server.
        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
            b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup).channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true).handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
                    .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                        @Override
                        public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                            ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
                            if (sslCtx != null) {
                                pipeline.addLast(sslCtx.newHandler(ch.alloc()));
                            }
                            pipeline.addLast("frameDecoder",new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(64*1024, 0, 8));
                            pipeline.addLast("frameEncoder", new LengthFieldPrepender(4));
                            pipeline.addLast(new ObjectDecoder(ClassResolvers.cacheDisabled(null)));
                            pipeline.addLast(new ObjectEncoder());

                            pipeline.addLast(new ChunkedWriteHandler());
                            pipeline.addLast(new FileServerHandler());
                        }
                    });

            // Start the server.
            ChannelFuture f = b.bind(PORT).sync();

            // Wait until the server socket is closed.
            f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}
```

FileServerHandler:

```
public class FileServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object obj) throws Exception {
        RandomAccessFile raf = null;
        long length = -1;
        try {
            ByteBuf buff = (ByteBuf)obj;

            byte[] bytes = new byte[buff.readableBytes()];
            buff.readBytes(bytes);

            String msg = new String(bytes);

            raf = new RandomAccessFile(msg, "r");
            length = raf.length();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ctx.writeAndFlush("ERR: " + e.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": " + e.getMessage() + '\n');
            return;
        } finally {
            if (length < 0 && raf != null) {
                raf.close();
            }
        }

        if (ctx.pipeline().get(SslHandler.class) == null) {
            // SSL not enabled - can use zero-copy file transfer.
            ctx.writeAndFlush(new DefaultFileRegion(raf.getChannel(), 0, length));
        } else {
            // SSL enabled - cannot use zero-copy file transfer.
            ctx.writeAndFlush(new ChunkedFile(raf));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Exception server.....");
    }
}
```

I referred [Netty In Action](https://www.manning.com/books/netty-in-action) and code samples from [here](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple things wrong with your server/client. First thing the SSL, for the client you don't need to initialize a SslContext for a server instead you would do something like this:

```
sslCtx = SslContextBuilder.forClient().trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE).build();
```

On the server side of things you use a `SelfSignedCertificate` which in itself isn't wrong but would like to remind you that it should only be used for debugging purposes and not in production. In addition you use the `ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE` which isn't recommended since the keepalive interval is OS-dependent. Furthermore you added `Object En-/Decoder` to your pipeline which in your case don't do anything useful so you can remove them.

Also you configured your `LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder` wrong due to an incomplete and wrong parameter *list*. In the [netty docs](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/codec/LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.html) you need the version of the constructor which defines the `lengthFieldLength` and `initialBytesToStrip`. Besides the not stripping the length field you also defined the wrong `lengthFieldLength` which should be the same as your `LengthFieldPrepender`'s `lengthFieldLength` which is 4 bytes. In conlusion you could use the constructor like this:

```
new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(64 * 1024, 0, 4, 0, 4)
```

In both your handler you don't specify a `Charset` when en-/decoding your `String` which could lead to problems because if no ´Charset´ is defined the systems default will be used which could vary. You could do something like this:

```
//to encode the String
string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

//to decode the String
new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Additionally you tried to use the `DefaultFileRegion` if no `SslHandler` was added to the pipeline which would have been fine if you didn't added the `LengthFieldHandler` since they would need a memory copy of the byte[] to send to added the length field. Moreover I would recommend using the `ChunkedNioFile` instead of the `ChunkedFile` because it's nonblocking which is always a good thing. You would do this like that:

```
new ChunkedNioFile(randomAccessFile.getChannel())
```

One final thing on how to *decode* a `ChunkedFile` as it's split in chunks you can simply assamble them tougether with a simple OutputStream. Here's an old file handler of mine:

```
public class FileTransferHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<ByteBuf> {

    private final Path path;
    private final int size;
    private final int hash;

    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private int writtenBytes = 0;
    private byte[] buffer = new byte[0];

    protected FileTransferHandler(Path path, int size, int hash) {
        this.path = path;
        this.size = size;
        this.hash = hash;
    }

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf byteBuf) throws Exception {
        if(this.outputStream == null) {
            Files.createDirectories(this.path.getParent());
            if(Files.exists(this.path))
                Files.delete(this.path);
            this.outputStream = Files.newOutputStream(this.path, StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        }

        int size = byteBuf.readableBytes();
        if(size > this.buffer.length)
            this.buffer = new byte[size];
        byteBuf.readBytes(this.buffer, 0, size);

        this.outputStream.write(this.buffer, 0, size);
        this.writtenBytes += size;

        if(this.writtenBytes == this.size && MurMur3.hash(this.path) != this.hash) {
            System.err.println("Received file has wrong hash");
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        if(this.outputStream != null)
            this.outputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank u for detailed answer. However, u mentioned that I shouldn't have used LengthFieldHandler, in case of DefaultFileRegion. 1. what does that mean ? 2. Also, the server would be receiving just the file name. So is it mandatory to use LengthFieldBasedDecoder at server side & LengthFieldPrepender at client side? On the other hand will the transfer of file use these LengthFieldBasedDecoder & LengthFieldPrepender handler ? 3. Where can I get more info to understand on how/when to use different encoders & decoders. Please guide me.

Comment: 1. Since DefaultFileRegion is a zero-copy file transfer your server cloudn't append the length field which then causes the client who is trying to decode the length field to recive a false length. 2. Because a file name is typically not very long it shouldn't be a problem to remove these LengthFieldHandler but a file can be large so it is recommend to use the length field for file transfer. 3. I don't really know. Since netty is open source I just go to there repo and look at the source itself to learn what which handler does in detail and how they work. https://github.com/netty/netty

Comment: Ingrim4 There's one more problem. This setting works for relatively small files (<4MB). For files larger than 4MB, only partial data is transferred (some times 2MB, 1.5MB). How to fix this? I checked at Server end, the complete data is sent out.

Comment: Would help if you opened another question cause without code that's hard to tell.